# Primefaces. Multiple row selection in datatable which is in modal dialog, ui:composition, layout

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

How can I perform multiple row selection in p:dataTable which is in dialog which has modal="true" and that dialog is in ui:composition element, and that ui composition element is placed in layout.

1 problem: (let's assume that for now p:dialog is not placed in layout)
you cannot perform multiple selection in p:dataTable which is wrapped by p:dialog element unless you remove appendToBody="true" and add transient="true". So now we have modal dialog which has p:dataTable with working multiple selection and everything is placed in ui:composition.
How does the form look like:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3c.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
template="/layout/layout.xhtml">
<ui:define>
<h:form>
    <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View" 
    update=":form:multiCars" onclick="dlg2.show();" type="button"/> 
</h:form>

<h:form id="form">   
  <p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Pasirinkimas" widgetVar="dlg2" 
modal="true" height="300" transient="true" resizable="false" selectionMode="multiple">  
  <p:dataTable id="multiCars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}">

    <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">  
        #{car.model}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:25%">  
        #{car.year}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">  
        #{car.manufacturer}  
    </p:column>  

    <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">  
        #{car.color}  
    </p:column>  

</p:dataTable>  

<p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
    update=":form:displayMulti" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show()" process="multiCars"/> 
  </p:dialog>
    <p:dialog id="multiDialog" header="Car Detail" widgetVar="multiCarDialog"  
        height="300" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="explode">  

            <p:dataList id="displayMulti" value="#{tableBean.selectedCars}" var="selectedCar">  
            Model: #{selectedCar.model}, Year: #{selectedCar.year}  
        </p:dataList>  
    </p:dialog>  
</h:form> 
</ui:define> 
</ui:composition>
```

2 problem.
The interesting part starts then this ui:composition is placed in layout. Then the shield of p:dialog goes in front of the dialog itself. The solution would be to add appendToBody="true", but then multiple selection stops working and it's not OK. Another solution would be to place dialog outside the layout element, but we are in ui:composition element, so that won't work. My final solution was just to disable p:dialog modal attribute by setting modal="false" but I'm not happy with it.

Is there any way how can one achieve multiple row selection in datatable which is placed in dialog, ui:composition and layout with turned p:dialog modal attribute on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that p:dialog had to be moved outside the form, and the form had to be put inside the dialog and appendToBody="true" property had to be added instead of transient="true"
So the code should look similarly to this one:

```
<p:dialog id="modalDialog" header="Pasirinkimas" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="300" appendToBody="true" resizable="false" selectionMode="multiple">  
  <h:form id="form">
  <p:dataTable id="multiCars" var="car" value="#{tableBean.mediumCarsModel}" paginator="true" rows="10" selection="#{tableBean.selectedCars}">

  <p:column headerText="Model" style="width:25%">  
    #{car.model}  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Year" style="width:25%">  
    #{car.year}  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Manufacturer" style="width:24%">  
    #{car.manufacturer}  
  </p:column>  

  <p:column headerText="Color" style="width:24%">  
    #{car.color}  
  </p:column>  

  </p:dataTable>  

  <p:commandButton id="multiViewButton" value="View" icon="ui-icon-search"  
update=":form:displayMulti" oncomplete="multiCarDialog.show()" process="multiCars"/> 
 </h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

It's because appendToBody="true" takes element outside the current context and attaches it to the bottom of the document body and so there is no form which wraps p:dialog, so we needed to insert form inside of the p:dialog.